# Current scroll offset inside a Flutter ListView, SliverList,etc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I get the current scroll offset inside a Flutter `ListView`, `GridView`, SliverList`, etc?

Answer (score 30):

- If you're inside the scroll view use `Scrollable.of(context).position.pixels`.
- If you're outside, you probably want to hand a `ScrollController` in as the controller argument of the scroll view, then you can read `controller.offset`.
- Alternatively, use scroll notifications with `NotificationListener`.

This was asked on Flutter Gitter, and answered:
https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter?at=591243f18a05641b1167be0e

Answer (score 25):

For someone else, looking for code implementation, you can use `ScrollController` like this:

- ##### Using `NotificationListener`:

  ```dart
  NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
      print(scrollNotification.metrics.pixels); // <-- This is it.
      return false;
    },
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 200,
      itemBuilder: (c, i) => Text('Item $i'),
    ),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `ScrollController.offset`

  ```dart
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      print(_controller.offset); // <-- This is it.
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: 200,
        itemBuilder: (c, i) => Text('Item $i'),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is with `NotificationListener`

```
NotificationListener(
  child: ListView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    children: ...
  ),
  onNotification: (notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
      print(_scrollController.position.pixels);
    }
    return false;
  },
)
```