# Find Flutter Scrollable by means of ScrollUpdateNotification

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a generic way of obtaining a reference to the Scrollable object which triggered a ScrollUpdateNotification.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881103/current-scroll-offset-inside-a-flutter-listview-sliverlist-etc) answer but only the last option seems viable, and ultimately seems to fall short. I can ascertain the scroll offset, but not a reference to the scrollable object itself.

Consider the following code...

```
final NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification> scrollNotifier = NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>(
      child: widget,
      onNotification: (ScrollUpdateNotification value) {
        ScrollableState scrollable1 = Scrollable.of(value.context);
        ScrollableState scrollable2 = Scrollable.of(context);
        return false;
      },
);
```

Both scrollables are always null. The first because value.context refers to the context of the gesture being listened to. The second because the context is that in which the NotificationListener exists. Is there any other way to achieve this generically?

Answer (score 3):

That is because when you do `Scrollable.of(context)`, internally it doesn't actually fetch the `Scrollable`.
It fetches a `_ScrollableScope` which holds the instance of `ScrollableState`.

The problem being, the widget tree is roughly similar to this:

```
Scrollable
  RawGestureDetector
    _ScrollableScope
```

Where it's the `RawGestureDetector`'s context that is passed to notifications.

---

Taking this into consideration, you can still obtain the `Scrollable` instance by doing the following:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    notification.context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<ScrollableState>());
  },
  child: child,
),
```

Comment: Note: I'll make a PR to fix this issue. But in the meantime you can do that

Comment: Perfect - Thanks Rémi! I've tested it and it works fine. I'll award the bounty when the system permits me. BTW you've got an extra closing bracket in your code. "()))".

Comment: @hunter You can follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/21157 to be able to do `Scrollable.of(context)`